# Ajax Pagination next and previous buttons doesn't work very well

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, pagination

I made my own custom pagination view. It works good. But when i was include ajax codes to pagination its broken. 1-2-3-4- ... buttons works fine.
But my main problem:

Next button is changing the page to second page.

Previous button is changing the page to first page.

Cannot jump to third page with next button when i was stay in second page.

In my controller:

```
$videos = Video::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(7);

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return view('frontend.videos.data', compact('videos'));
    }
        return view('frontend.videos', compact('videos'));
```

In the view:

```
<div id="video-gallery" class="row mt-10px" style="width: 100%;margin: 0;">
        @include('frontend.videos.data')
    </div>

    {!! $videos->links('paginations.custom'); !!}
```

And this is the ajax codes:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        if (window.location.hash) {
            var page = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
            if (page == Number.NaN || page <= 0) {
                return false;
            }else{
                getData(page);
            }
        }
    });


    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(document).on('click', '.pagination a',function(event)
        {
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
            event.preventDefault();


            var myurl = $(this).attr('href');
            var page=$(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];


            getData(page);
        });
    });


    function getData(page){
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '?page=' + page,
                type: "get",
                datatype: "html",
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $("#video-gallery").empty().html(data);
                $videoLightGallery.data('lightGallery').destroy(true);
                $videoLightGallery.lightGallery();
                //location.hash = page;
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                alert('No Response From Server');
            });
    }
</script>
@endsection
```

I hope somebody can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working

Answer (score 0):

When you are updating the page, you should also update the Previous and Next buttons `href` attribute. They are server-side rendered and will only contain the correct href on a fresh page load.

So

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    // Update href tags.
    // Not giving everything away ;)
});
```

Comment: Please help me on the pagination issue.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316910/magento-2-custom-added-ajax-pagination-not-working